# Infopath 2010 field using External Data Connection of SharePoint BCS

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010, bcs

I created an Infopath 2010, which I am then publishing to SharePoint in a forms library. My first field is a BCS field, which is pulling from CRM.

I set-up my external data field, and when I type in a name it will run the check to confirm that it is from CRM. However, if I try to use the picker it throws the error:

> An error occurred while obtaining business data by using the Picker
>   web service. Contact your system administrator.

I have been unable to find any information regarding this error, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you create a different list with this external type, does it work as expected? is the type .NET? if so, you could do some logging in the Constructor/ReadItem/ReadList method. i suspect its a permission/authentication issue...

Comment: I was able to create a standard SP list, and use SharePoint's out-of-the box external functionality for a field item. However, I need to edit the form in InfoPath, and I can't do that if I just add the field to a standard SP list. I am not sure what you mean by type .Net. It's just an out-of-the box Infopath form.

Comment: what i meant is, how did you define this external-type field? usually you do it via SharePoint Designer right?

Comment: I didn't actually create the field myself. I know that it is using SharePoint's Business Data Connectivity service, and that it was created in SharePoint's Central Administration, and is speaking to CRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the answer was staring me in the face, and I just didn't see it the whole time. (I'm almost embarrassed to admit it!)

I had told the form to connect to the external data source through SharePoint; however the form was actually opening in InfoPath, and not via SharePoint's built in browser form. As soon as I went into the advanced settings, and said to use the browser form, and not the client application the web picker worked perfectly.

Thank you for your assistance on this issue Andreas. It was greatly appreciated.